# How can I summarise a sparse pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
            Date  A   B   C
0     2020-08-17  1   1   0
1     2020-08-17  1   0   0
2     2020-08-17  0   0   1
3     2020-08-18  0   1   0
4     2020-08-18  1   1   0
5     2020-08-19  0   0   1
...
```

A,B,C columns have values that are either 0 or 1. I already filtered out rows that have only zero values, so all rows should have at least a "1".

First I want to get the following result:

```
df2
            Date  A   B   C
0     2020-08-17  2   1   1
3     2020-08-18  1   2   0
4     2020-08-19  0   0   1
...
```

Then I want to get this result:

```
df3
            Date  Summary
0     2020-08-17  A=2|B=1|C=1 
1     2020-08-18  A=1|B=2
2     2020-08-19  C=1
...
```

What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: What the rationale  to summarize it that way?

Comment: By summarizing your DF like that, you make it useless for further processing. Think again.

Comment: It's actually a very sparse dataframe that has 30 columns and 80% 0s. I don't need to do any further processing after I get the end result.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC I have a specific need for this representation for a niche application and I got the solution I wanted.

Comment: @MoB That does not invalidate the fact that the question is quite bare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we do

```
s1 = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).sum()
Out[5]: 
         Date  A  B  C
0  2020-08-17  2  1  1
1  2020-08-18  1  2  0
2  2020-08-19  0  0  1
```

Then

```
s = s1.melt('Date')
s = s[s.value!=0]

s2 = (s.variable + '=' + s.value.astype(str)).groupby(s.Date).agg('|'.join).reset_index(name='col')
Out[17]: 
         Date          col
0  2020-08-17  A=2|B=1|C=1
1  2020-08-18      A=1|B=2
2  2020-08-19          C=1
```

Comment: good answer, what does as_index=False do here, cant understand from the document?

Comment: @A.B do not set the groupby key as index ~

Comment: df[['A','B','C']]=df[['A','B','C']].astype(int) @MoB

Comment: @BEN_YO thank you, your solution worked perfectly. I just needed to cast the numbers to int.